# parse JSON object with value passed as single quote string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I an getting aws event parameter as follow  in the lambda call. 
`let event = { pathParameters: '{"foo":"35314"}' }`

When I am trying to validate the parameter in condition , it cant find `foo` key on `pathParameters`

Here my condition check

```
if (event.pathParameters && event.pathParameters.foo) {
   //do something
} else {
   console.log('fail');
}
```

It going in `else` condition . I tried `JSON.parse(JSON.strinify(event))`. It did not help. I do get the Object if I do `JSON.parse(event.pathParameters)`.
Any way to resolve the issue on root level object.

Comment: try `JSON.parse(event.pathParameters).foo`

Comment: You have to parse it--it's a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't *parse* the `event` to get access to the `'{"foo": "35314}'"`, you need to parse the `event.pathParameters` value to get the actual `foo` and its value, `35314`

```js
let event = { pathParameters: '{"foo":"35314"}' }

if (event.pathParameters && JSON.parse(event.pathParameters).foo) {
   console.log("'foo' =", JSON.parse(event.pathParameters).foo);
} else {
   console.log('fail');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the data that you are getting has JSON as stringified in `pathParameters`, so you'll have to parse with that key something like

```
JSON.parse(event.pathParameters).foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let event = { pathParameters: '{"foo":"35314"}' } // foo is a string

if (event.pathParameters) {
   try {
      const { foo } = JSON.parse(event.pathParameters);
      // use foo
   } catch (jsonError) {
     console.log('There was some json parse error', jsonError);
   } 
} else {
   console.log('fail');
}
```

You need to parse the data from `event.pathParameters`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doSomething(event) {
  let pathParametersObj = JSON.parse(event.pathParameters);
  if (pathParametersObj && pathParametersObj.foo) {
    //do something
    console.log('pass');
  } else {
    console.log('fail');
  }
}

let event1 = {
  pathParameters: '{"foo":"35314"}'
}

let event2 = {
  pathParameters: null
}

doSomething(event1);
doSomething(event2);
```